# Do wireless amplifiers work in both directions?

Tags: amplifier, signal, wifi

I'm especially wondering about wifi aplifiers (2.4GHz and 5GHz).
I have a couple of very basic questions about them. (I hope this is not too much for a single question):

- Are there special signal amplifiers for routers and for client machines or would the same amplifier work on both? (I'm wondering because [this one](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/4W-Wifi-Wireless-Broadband-Amplifier-Router-2-4Ghz-Power-Range-Signal-Booster-Free-Shipping/2035126682.html) says "don't connect with network card".)
- Does a signal amplifier work in both directions (upload and download) even if only one of the two parities is using such a device? (The one linked above says "bi-directional", has this anything to do with this?)
- If it would actually work for both (sending data and receiving data): how does this work? I get that you can use an amplifier to make your sending signals stronger, but are the amplifiers also be able to better pick up weak signals?

(I am well aware of the strict laws related to transmit power limits etc.)

Comment: Short answer: NO, amplifiers work in only **one** direction. The module from your link is unsuitable for people like you who have **no clue** about how transceivers work. If you want to learn about RF and transceivers, good for you, start reading some books about it. If you just want to increase your Wifi range (that's what I suspect) you will **FAIL** if you try to do that with a booster. Get a Wifi repeater or an extra access point. Those work and are 100% legal.

Comment: You don't have to know how they work to use them properly. ;) There is certainly no need to read a book about it. Some minutes of research on the Internet will do. That being said, using a signal amplifyer for 2.4GHz is not illegal in my country as long as you leave the transmitting power under a certain limit. And yes I have all the equipment to measure that out.

Comment: If you know everything already or it can be found on the internet, why are you asking a question here then ? Why are you asking if an amplifier is bidirectional when you later say that you don't need to know that in order to use it ? Obviously you **do not** want to understand **how** things work so why are you asking ?

Comment: @FakeMoustache I'm totally onboard with your comments.  As a matter of interest perhaps, I have a full duplex transceiver made of Esaki diodes.  I'm sure there's a few other esoteric exceptions.  There's currently the nZero work through DARPA that might come out with some full duplex amplifiers.   Now that we can get a circulator on an IC, we probably will see more things that "appear" to be full duplex.  The SPAR BAA work is duplex front ends.  Just some random trivia to displace other random trivia.

Comment: @FakeMoustache Wow what is wrong with you. Calm down, alright? Neither have I ever claimed to "know everything", nor have I claimed that "everything can be found on the Internet". I'm simply asking how something works and I could not find helpful information about it. I basically already know how to use it and I know there are tutorials online that show how you can safely use such an amplifier to improve your wifi experience without affecting others. Being able to use something doesn't mean you have to have read books about how it `works`... Knowing how to use it is simply not the same thing.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with me, it is you who asks a question about bi-directional amplifiers while you should have asked: *Can I use this amplifier to extend my Wifi range ?* If you don't want to understand **how** something works **fine** but then do not ask about it. Your question says *wondering about...* but then later in your first comment you don't want to know how they work. Ask a clear question then ! You already decided for yourself that an amplifier would be a good solution while it isn't (see Dave's answer).

Comment: @FakeMoustache There is nothing wrong with you? Is that why you are talking to me in that tone of voice, completely overreacting, accusing me of things and basically insulting me? You apparently don't even remotely know what I'm planning to do. I'm not continuing this discussion with you. Not until you change your tone of voice, anyways. Have a good one.

Comment: *You apparently don't even remotely know what I'm planning to do.* Precisely, because your question was unclear about it. So I gave some comment, tried to answer what (I thought) you were asking and then **you** complain that that is not what you need. Fair enough but then be **clear what you want** in your question and stop complaining that I don't give you the information you are looking for. It's not me, it's **you** who is overreacting because you get an answer you do not want to hear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No. They are the same. Likely they don't want you to use a USB network adapter for other design reasons (like how most of them don't have the RF link that you need to attach to this board, they instead have internal antenna and their own compensation networks).
2. Yes. Technically speaking an RF amplifier only works in one direction. This board likely either uses two amplifiers which are time division multiplexed or has only one amplifier and a time division multiplex back to the receiver without any amplification. (If they are fancy and thoughtful, they might even be using an active isolator).
3. As I described above, the incoming signal is routed to a different amplifier, "facing" the other way. This way neither amplifier can drive the other (amplifiers go poof), nor can the other amplifier use the antenna at that time (no garbled signals from talking and listening at the same time on an antenna that might not be perfect).

This is all very abstract and high level of explanation and the exact details aren't perfect. It's not my design. I've never seen this before in my life. I don't generally trust Chinese designs unless they release a parts list. The board is also missing its RF connectors, which makes me dislike it even more. (Honestly, it's a bit shady to have an RF board without any RF connectors. Like I can literally see the solder points but they are so obviously designed for a side mount standard coaxial screw that I wonder why they're not there.)

Comment: I'd say the connectors are missing to make this thing as cheap as possible. I actually prefer it this way because depending on the case you will use for it you would chose different connectors. Like 90° angled ones or some with screws on, or female on the one side and male on the other side... Or maybe instead of RP-SMA you want U.FL...

Comment: But back to the topic. So it is really possible to pick up a signal that is so weak that other wifi adapters don't even see it and amplify it so that it is usable again? Wouldn't this introduce some kind of unwanted "noise"? Like a microphone would if you tried to pick up someone speaking a mile away from you?

Comment: @Forivin be aware that 4 W of WiFi is most likely illegal in most jurisdictions. While the board might very well boost the uplink range, it will do little to the downlink. Yes, it does have a 10 dB downlink amplifier as well, but if the downlink signal is already swamped in noise you will amplify the noise as well leading to little improvement. Other devices will receive data more reliably, but your end won't unless you stick these to *both* ends. I'd suggest ditching these and getting repeaters.

Comment: @Forivin, There are techniques to reduce noise like spectrum windowing and other things, but yes, eventually you will run out of signal to noise head room and have your signal lost in the noise. But, just as jms says, these are *likely* **highly** illegal in your local area (Pretty sure I can say the entirety of the USA and Canada and European Union) plus it's only really of benefit if both ends have this type of amplification board unless you only care about unidirectional communication.

Comment: @Forivin, You couldn't use u.fl on this board. Like I said, those solder points are made for only threaded type connectors that mount at a 90 degree angle. u.fl wouldn't be able to attach to that solder point. So if you really want a female on one side and a male on the other I guess this could be helpful, but most of the time it's easier to get a cable that does the conversion than to take the time to solder a different contact.

Comment: @David Well, maybe you don't want to directly solder the connector on the board. E.g. you could screw [a connector like this](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/NEW-RP-SMA-Female-Jack-RF-Coax-Connector-4-hole-flange-solder-post-Straight-Insulator-Long/32458131292.html) in a case and connect it to the board using cables. And why would you only be able to solder 90° connectors to it? [This one](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/3pcs-Connector-RP-SMA-male-JACK-pin-solder-PCB-clip-edge-mount-ST-RF-COAXIAL/1990645192.html) for instance should work fine.

Comment: @David And yes, 4 Watts would be ridiculous. I'm planning to go from from around 15dBm to 27dBm which should be around 500mW and is perfectly legal where I live at the moment.

Comment: @Forivin, that second connector you linked is infact supposed to be mounted parallel with the board (or 90 degrees from normal as most components go). The reason you can't mount it another way has to do with strain on the solder joints as wells as RF continuity. But that's neither here nor there. Remember that some places have laws that are particularly strict such as making the end user unable to exceed a given power limit except by modifying the circuit. I'll accept that you know the laws better where you're at than I do, but I'm still advising caution and wish you luck on your project.